# How can I get a specific time Today in UTC java

Tags: java, datetime, java-8, java-time, java.time.instant

I am trying to get a specific time in UTC for "today". 
Say 5pm UTC

`Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS)`

OR

`Instant.now().plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS)`

This i believe gets me to midnight current day. Do I just extend this

`Instant.now().truncatedTo(ChronoUnit.DAYS).plus(1, ChronoUnit.DAYS).minus(7, ChronoUnit.HOURS);`

Or is there a better way to do this.

Comment: Or better yet, the next time its 5pm UTC.

Comment: There is no guaranty to get “5pm” through arithmetic from an instant.

Comment: Thanks. Any other approach you suggest to get a specific UTC time for "today".

Comment: @Holger, `Instant` also supports `with(LocalTime)`, so it should not be very hard.

Comment: My bad: Instant actually doesn't support that. For some reason, there is no support for `nano-of-day` chrono field, which is what LocalTime uses for representing itself as a single value.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov: you can use `LocalDate.now().atTime(17, 0).toInstant(ZoneOffset.UTC)`; I never said, it was hard, only that you should not try to use *arithmetic on an instant*, as “5pm” does not necessarily imply “7 hours before midnight”…

Comment: @Holger, yes, that is true, adding or subtracting something to dates ignores a lot of details about them, so preferred solution to get some specific date-time is to construct it rather than compute.

Comment: An `Instant` is conceptually just a point on the time line. Don’t think of it as being inherently UTC. Use `OffsetDateTime` for calculating the desired date and time in UTC and then convert to `Instant` using `OffsetDateTime.toInstant()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That would be something along these lines

```
ZonedDateTime now = ZonedDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// this would be the today (might be in the past)
ZonedDateTime result = now.with(LocalTime.of(17, 0));
if (result.isBefore(now)) {
  // This would be "next time it is 5 o-clock".
  result = result.plusDays(1);
}
// if you really want an Instant out of it.
return result.toInstant();
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give this a shot.

Comment: `OffsetDateTime` will do just as well. Otherwise a good answer.